# Get current RotationAngle while Animation is running on Android

Tags: android, animation, image-rotation

I'm rotating an `ImageView` by using an `Animation` defined by a *XML* file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <rotate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:fillAfter="true" />    
</set>
```

Although `ImageView` has the `getRotation()` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) , it only returns the first value that has been set to the image object.

Is there anyway to get the current rotation degrees by using a *XML animation*? If not, what should be the best way to go with it?

Comment: use a ValueAnimator/ObjectAnimator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    private ObjectAnimator rotationAnimator;

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRotation(float rotation) {
        super.setRotation(rotation);
        // Do something
    }

    public synchronized void startAnimation(int animationDuration) {

        if (rotationAnimator == null || !rotationAnimator.isRunning()) {
            Keyframe kf0 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0f, 0f);
            Keyframe kf2 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0.5f, 180f);
            Keyframe kf1 = Keyframe.ofFloat(1f, 360f);

            PropertyValuesHolder pvhRotation = PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe("rotation", kf0, kf1, kf2);
            rotationAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this, pvhRotation);
            rotationAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            rotationAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            rotationAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
            rotationAnimator.start();
        }
        else {
            // Already running
        }
    }
```

Version 2, since you are having problems

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    private ObjectAnimator rotationAnimator;
    private float myRotation;

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setMyRotation(float rotation) {
        this.myRotation = rotation;
        Log.d("CustomImage", "Rotation: " + rotation);
        invalidate();
    }

    public synchronized void startAnimation(int animationDuration) {

        if (rotationAnimator == null || !rotationAnimator.isRunning()) {
            Keyframe kf0 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0f, 0f);
            Keyframe kf2 = Keyframe.ofFloat(0.5f, 180f);
            Keyframe kf1 = Keyframe.ofFloat(1f, 360f);

            PropertyValuesHolder pvhRotation = PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe("myRotation", kf0, kf1, kf2);
            rotationAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this, pvhRotation);
            rotationAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            rotationAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            rotationAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
            rotationAnimator.start();
        }
        else {
            // Already running
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stopAnimation() {
        if (rotationAnimator != null) {
            rotationAnimator.cancel();
            rotationAnimator = null;
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean getAnimationRunning() {
        return rotationAnimator != null && rotationAnimator.isRunning();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.rotate(myRotation, getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Sample logcat output:

```
04-22 22:48:55.475  16341-16341/animation.example.com.animationdemo D/CustomImage﹕ Rotation: 358.44
04-22 22:48:55.490  16341-16341/animation.example.com.animationdemo D/CustomImage﹕ Rotation: 0.48000813
04-22 22:48:55.505  16341-16341/animation.example.com.animationdemo D/CustomImage﹕ Rotation: 2.4
04-22 22:48:55.525  16341-16341/animation.example.com.animationdemo D/CustomImage﹕ Rotation: 4.44
```

I have packed the code into a simple project: [LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91522375/AnimationDemo.zip)

Comment: Where should I define my ImageView for this *ObjectAnimator*?

Comment: I just implemented the *CustomImageView*. App is running, image is being shown, but the animation doesn't start inside my *Fragment*.
    CustomImageView agulhaV  = (CustomImageView) l.findViewById(R.id.agulha_volt);
    agulhaV.startAnimation(3000);

Comment: It runs just fine on my end. I will make a quick sample project.

Comment: I have put a link to a simple project, try it out. It works just fine :)

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could upvote twice. Therefore, everything is *almost* working fine, since I'm getting all the time Rotation: 0 at the Logcat

Comment: Really? That's weird. How would it then rotate the image if would be 0 for the whole time?

Comment: The image doesn't rotate.. would be because of the Fragment?

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't rotate. I am using this code to rotate a custom progress bar and it runs just fine in a dialog. Also in the sample it runs in the activity. :/

Comment: Try the version 2 where I am doing the actual rotation

Comment: Not working neither. Is there any reason that could cause it since I'm using eclipse?

Comment: No idea, I tried both versions on all of the devices I could get my hands on  and it works (just for the good measure). Also never got any feedback from users that the progressbar would not be rotating.

Comment: Canvas method `canvas.rotate(45, getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f);` does changes the degrees but `myRotation` is always 0.

Comment: are you using nineolddroids?